# Setting up Azure VPN Client on VirtualBox guest OS

Tags: linux, virtualbox, azure

I have VirtualBox installed on Linux Mint (host). The guest OS is Windows 10. The guest OS is used for windows based/Azure development with Visual Studio.
The application I am developing a ASP.NET Core, and deploys to Azure. The sql database is on Azure.

In order to test the application, I need to have the VPN connected so I can access the database and storage account.

I have installed the Azure VPN Client on the guest OS. The VPN connects, and remains connected for about a minute, and then disconnects with a fail message.

Is this because the guest and host network are not set up correctly?
I am not sure what to do. I have looked through as many similar posts but I can't find something related to Linux being the host.